# find number of paths (ending at leaves) where the sum of the elements in the path is equal to the number passed

Tags: java, binary-tree

Given a binary tree you need to find number of paths (ending at leaves) where the sum of the elements in the path is equal to the number passed.

Getting Error in my code .

E.g. if tree is 
      10
  5        12
4  7
and number passed is 22

than we have two paths 10->5->7 and 10->12 where the sum is 22. So, the answer is 2.

E.g. if tree is
      10
  5        12
4  7    1    3
and number passed is 22

than we have only one path 10->5->7 as 12 is not a leaf node and adding 1 or 3 increases the value above 22. So, the answer is 1.

// Java program to print to print root to leaf path sum equal to
// a given number

/* A binary tree node has data, pointer to left child
and a pointer to right child */

```
class Node 
{
    int data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(int item) 
    {
        data = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {
int count =0;
    Node root;

    /*
    Given a tree and a sum, return true if there is a path from the root
    down to a leaf, such that adding up all the values along the path
    equals the given sum.

    Strategy: subtract the node value from the sum when recurring down,
    and check to see if the sum is 0 when you run out of tree.
    */

    int haspathSum(Node node, int sum) 
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return (count=0);
        }
        else
        {

            /* otherwise check both subtrees */
            int subsum = sum - node.data;

            if (subsum == 0 && node.left == null && node.right == null)
                    count = count + 1;
                    //return count;
        if node.left
                haspathSum(node.left, subsum);
                //return count;
            if (node.right)
                haspathSum(node.right, subsum);

            return count;

        }

    }


    /* Driver program to test the above functions */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        int sum = 22;

        /* Constructed binary tree is
            10
            / \
        8    2
        / \ /
        3 5 2
        */
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        tree.root = new Node(10);
        tree.root.left = new Node(5);
        tree.root.right = new Node(12);
        tree.root.left.left = new Node(4);
        tree.root.left.right = new Node(7);
        //tree.root.right.left = new Node(2);

//  BinaryTree ch = new BinaryTree();
            System.out.println("count = " +tree.haspathSum(tree.root,sum));
    }       

}
```

Error :--

```
46: error: incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to boolean
        if (node.left)
                ^
49: error: incompatible types: Node cannot be converted to boolean
            if (node.right)
                    ^
2 errors
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Do you mean `if (node.left!=null)` ?

Comment: Thank you to tell silly error .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're using a value of type Node where a boolean was expected. In other languages like C and JavaScript **null** automatically evaluates to false in *if* expressions but it doesn't in Java.

I think you wanted to write `if (node.left != null)`, and the same for `node.right`.